# Is it possible to use raw SQL with python's django web framework?

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm switching from PHP to Django/Python, and one thing I don't really like about django so far is the ORM. When inserting new rows, it's fine, but when I want to SELECT something more specific, I find that the ORM is more troublesome than pure SQL, specially since I already know SQL quite well.

So, can I write pure SQL in Django, or I am forced to use the ORM?

If it's possible, examples on how to use SQL in django would be very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using `.raw()`? That should be what you're looking for. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! You can.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/

From Django's awesome documentation;

There are two ways;

1. using a manager method `raw()`

   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries

   ```
   class Person(models.Model):
       first_name = models.CharField(...)
       last_name = models.CharField(...)
       birth_date = models.DateField(...)
   ```

   You could then execute custom SQL like so:

   ```
   >>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
   ...     print(p)
   John Smith
   Jane Jones
   ```

   Use the following method to pass parameters.

   ```
   >>> lname = 'Doe'
   >>> Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE last_name = %s', [lname])
   ```
2. Executing custom SQL directly.

   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

   ```
   from django.db import connection
   def my_custom_sql(self):
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
       cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
       row = cursor.fetchone()
   return row
   ```

Comment: And be sure you don't forget to pass parameters as parameters, or you end up having your database SQL-injected!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 3):

yes, it is. Suppose you have a model like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField('bar', max_length=32)
```

you could write

```
Foo.objects.raw("SELECT bar from appname__foo LIMIT 5;")
```

or whatever SQL you like. the key is to use `models.Model.objects.raw` method.

It is up to you to make sure the query returns Foo objects though